# Use a slider to shift only one scatter trace in time in plotly

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-python

I have a scatter (line) plot with several traces.  I would like to be able to shift one trace forward and backward in time, while the others remain fixed.

I can achieve this by creating multiple traces with preset offsets but this is results is a huge file (18mb vs 4mb w/o all the steps).  Is it possible to update the data of the trace with the slider?

plot w/o slider:

```
import pandas as pd
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

data = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/simonmcconnell/42654e09f17805f63b2afa2cdc7166c1/raw/5dbed5a14bc6db6912420d5a1ae4e82e173f6a34/sampledata.csv"

col_names = [
    "DATE",
    "TIME",
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
]

dtypes = {
    "A": "float64",
    "B": "float64",
    "C": "float64",
}

df = pd.read_csv(
    data,
    header=0,
    names=col_names,
    dtype=dtypes,
    parse_dates=[["DATE", "TIME"]],
    infer_datetime_format=True,
    dayfirst=True,
    cache_dates=True,
    skipinitialspace=True,
)

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df["DATE_TIME"],
        y=df["B"],
        mode="lines",
        name="B",
    ),
    secondary_y=False,
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df["DATE_TIME"],
        y=df["C"],
        mode="lines",
    ),
    secondary_y=False,
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df["DATE_TIME"],
        y=df["A"],
        mode="lines",
    ),
    secondary_y=True,
)

fig.write_html("no_offset.html", auto_open=True)
```

plot with slider:

```
from datetime import timedelta

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import humanize
import plotly.graph_objects as go
from plotly.subplots import make_subplots

data = "https://gist.githubusercontent.com/simonmcconnell/42654e09f17805f63b2afa2cdc7166c1/raw/5dbed5a14bc6db6912420d5a1ae4e82e173f6a34/sampledata.csv"

col_names = [
    "DATE",
    "TIME",
    "A",
    "B",
    "C",
]

dtypes = {
    "A": "float64",
    "B": "float64",
    "C": "float64",
}

df = pd.read_csv(
    data,
    header=0,
    names=col_names,
    dtype=dtypes,
    parse_dates=[["DATE", "TIME"]],
    infer_datetime_format=True,
    dayfirst=True,
    cache_dates=True,
    skipinitialspace=True,
)

fig = make_subplots(specs=[[{"secondary_y": True}]])

sample_period = (df["DATE_TIME"][1] - df["DATE_TIME"][0]).total_seconds()
step_size = 30
sample_count = len(df)
slider_positions = 60

for step in np.arange(0, slider_positions, 1):
    fig.add_trace(
        go.Scatter(
            visible=False,
            x=df["DATE_TIME"].truncate(
                after=sample_count - step_size * step / sample_period - 1
            ),
            y=df["B"].truncate(before=step_size * step / sample_period - 1),
            mode="lines",
            name="Offset Trace",
        ),
        secondary_y=False,
    )
fig.data[0].visible = True

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df["DATE_TIME"],
        y=df["C"],
        mode="lines",
    ),
    secondary_y=False,
)

fig.add_trace(
    go.Scatter(
        x=df["DATE_TIME"],
        y=df["A"],
        mode="lines",
    ),
    secondary_y=True,
)

steps = []
for i in range(1, slider_positions):
    step = dict(
        method="restyle", args=["visible", [False] * slider_positions + [True] * 3],
    )
    step["args"][1][i] = True
    step["label"] = humanize.naturaldelta(timedelta(seconds=i * 30))
    steps.append(step)

sliders = [
    dict(
        active=slider_positions,
        currentvalue={"prefix": "Offset: "},
        pad={"t": 250},
        steps=steps,
    )
]

fig.update_layout(sliders=sliders)

fig.write_html("time_offset.html", auto_open=True)
```

Comment: This is an interesting question. But it's hard to provide a good suggestion without a proper dataset. Please consider sharing a sample of your data, or putting together a dataset that at least resembles the structure of your real world data.

Comment: Apologies, I have uploaded a dataset and fleshed out the examples.